# Apache virtual host proxy to nginx for ruby

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, proxy

I'm running a few php sites off apache and want to start rails dev.

I've installed rvm/nginx and can get my ruby site by going to websiteroot.com:8000...

How do I pass ruby.websiteroot.com to websiteroot.com:8000?

What's the best way for me to route a subdomain for ruby dev?? I'd switch to nginx completely if it weren't for all my php sites--seems like it's easier to just proxy for ruby.

Advice?

My nginx config looks like this:

```
server{
  listen 8000;
  server_name website.com;
  root /home/me/sites/ruby_folder/public;
  ...
}
```

My apache config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost>
  ServerName ruby.website.com
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is?  You're preserving the host header from the client request.  Is that not what you're seeing sent to nginx?

Comment: I'm not sure if nginx is seeing anything, but I'm fairly certain that apache is seeing a request.  I'm a noob...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listen: 8000;` is invalid syntax - it should be `listen 8000;`.  Is nginx even starting successfully?

Comment: You're right. My typo... Nginx is starting correctly.

Comment: Ok - so can you clarify what your issue is?  What happens when you attempt to access the site with a browser?

Comment: You can see it now: pixelcraftwebdesign.com:8000 works, but ruby.pixelcraftwebdesign.com doesn't...I don't know why.  I want the subdomain to point to the 8000 port, I think.

Comment: The DNS name `ruby.pixelcraftwebdesign.com` does not resolve to an IP address.  How is your DNS configured?

Comment: Not sure. What do you need to know?

Comment: Looks like it's served by a provider?  Can you check how that name is configured in their DNS management tool?

Comment: I can. I'm not sure what you mean--I can make subdomains work fine through apache httpd.conf, but I'm just not sure about forwarding it to nginx on port 8000.

Comment: What I mean is that a query for that name (`dig ruby.pixelcraftwebdesign.com @8.8.8.8`) results in an `NXDOMAIN` response - the name doesn't exist in public DNS.

Comment: Grrrrrr. What about anything.pixelcraftwebdesign.com? All other subdomains point to the root, I think...

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the case - `NXDOMAIN` responses on those as well.  How was the name resolution configured with your provider?

Comment: Oh, my goodness. You're right. Is it a DNS issue? Sorry for spinning your wheels...

Comment: There's definitely a DNS issue - there may also be other issues, too, but the DNS will need to be worked out before we find those.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks for pointing out my stupidity.

Comment: Welp, Shane. I'm a idiot. It definitely was a DNS issue. Thank you!!!

Comment: Would you midify your answer to suit our discovery?